# virtualization and active domain controller solution for my network

Tags: networking, active-directory, virtualization

Before I'll move on I'd like to hear your thoughts about what would be the best solution for my network.

In short I'm looking the best solution for my network of an high school which contains up to 100 PCs.
What I'd like to know is which would be the best approach for the computer lab room, for now I have PCs there but I'm thinking to a virtualization in order to maintain all of them more easily...

What will be the recommended hardware specs of the server? or do I need more than one? (any examples are welcomed)

maybe it would be better to think forward, be prepared also for an upgrade to 200 PCs to...

UPDATE:
At first sorry for missdetaling of what I wanted to do...
For now in lab room I have 30 PCs which are running Windows XP SP3 and for each PC I'm limiting it using Windows SteadyState but it really comes paintfull when need to do some changes for all of them. The type of the applications would be only windows based and educational ones (to give you an example would be: MS Offfice, AutCAD, CodeBlocks any any others similar to this ones).
I was thinking to an active domain in irder to limit them from my server (I think I'll choose Windows 2008 R2 server) but for now I'm using PCs but I'd plan to moove to a virtualization network.

I was asking your you guys in order to see any recomandation of an hardware server also...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a pooled desktop solution but I think that the setup and cost would outweigh the savings from maintenance.  200 desktops should not be that difficult to maintain.  I'd take a look at setting up a better management solution like system center configuration manager or Altiris client management.  As Bart said, any sort of desktop virtualization, really requires a managed environment.

Comment: updated my question, srry for missdetaling

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're asking here...how would virtualization help your lab of 100 PCs? And you don't give any specs...how are they used, what are you trying to do, what applications...

My only guess is that you mean terminal servers, not virtualization. Two very different things.

If you're running applications similar to what we run in USA for education, terminal services most likely will not work unless you have a very controlled environment and you don't allow user's whims to dictate software installed ("That MUST be used.") So unless there are specific circumstances, I say don't use terminals for general lab usage in school situations, unless it's for a very limited scope of application use.

Even if you wanted to move forward with terminal services (I can give some horror stories and pitfalls) you don't say what you're using, what kind of applications, how hard the servers will be hit, etc. so it's impossible to answer the question.

Comment: He could be asking about VDI, which is kind of a hybrid between virtualization and terminal services.

Comment: He could be, but the description is still too vague in my opinion to answer.

Comment: @BartSilverstrim: updated my question... Sorry for miss detaling for the first time